# python-augeas, yum update error in CentOS7

Tags: python, yum, centos7, augeas

I'm coming across this error below when I run: `sudo yum update`

```
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for base
python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch.rpm                       |  25 kB   00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch                             1/2 
Error unpacking rpm package python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch                             1/2 
python-augeas-0.4.1-5.el7.noarch was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : python-augeas-0.4.1-5.el7.noarch                             2/2 

Failed:
  python-augeas.noarch 0:0.4.1-5.el7     python-augeas.noarch 0:0.5.0-2.el7    

Complete!
```

I see that the update is expecting a file to be removed. My plan was to find it and remove and then try the update again. However, `find -iname "python-augeas-0.4.1-5.el7.noarch"` doesn't return anything for me, so I have my doubts that removing that file is the way to go.

Admittedly I'm not a sys admin or even very competent when it comes to stuff like this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

EDIT 1:

As suggested by Michael Hampton, here are the permissions and attributes:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jun 29  2015 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info


$ lsattr -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info
---------------- /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

---

EDIT 2:

I uninstalled the package with `sudo yum remove python-augeas`. I then reinstalled with the following error:

```
$ sudo yum install python-augeas
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, remove-with-leaves
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.rit.edu
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirrors.rit.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-augeas.noarch 0:0.5.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch                             Version                                Repository                      Size
======================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python-augeas                           noarch                           0.5.0-2.el7                            base                            25 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 25 k
Installed size: 71 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch.rpm                                                                                           |  25 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch                                                                                                   1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch                                                                                                   1/1 

Failed:
  python-augeas.noarch 0:0.5.0-2.el7                                                                                                                  

Complete!
```

---

EDIT 3:

Michael Hampton was correct about the permissions of my directory:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
drwxr-xr-x. 161 root root 12288 Jan 14 12:47 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Solution:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
sudo yum install -y python-augeas
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to have perms 777 is not a good solution. I am also suspicious that this was the fix because by using `sudo` you are running as superuser and should have permissions on that directory no matter what (excluding more complicated ACLs).

This error can also happen if the python module was installed a different way. Is the module in `pip list`? If yes, then running `sudo pip uninstall augeas` before installing it with `yum` should resolve the problem.

You don't want to mix package managers if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because yum could not remove the old copy of the named file, `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info`.

This may be because the permissions are set incorrectly, or an immutable attribute is set.

Check the permissions and attributes for the named file/directory, and of the containing directory, and fix any problems. Then try the update again.

```
ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info
lsattr -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_augeas-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info
ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
lsattr -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your suggestion. I checked the permissions and attributes as suggested, but I'm not quite sure how to spot problems as you suggest. I edited my original question to include the permissions and attributes. Could you please tell me if you see a problem because it isn't so obvious to me.

Comment: @alfonso Try again: this is a directory, so you need to pass `-d` to both commands to get the right information.

Comment: Michael, my mistake. Please see my latest edit. Is that what you meant? Any errors are not obvious to me from this output.

Comment: @alfonso Everything there looks right. I'd try uninstalling the package, and then reinstalling it.

Comment: Michael, I was able to uninstall with `sudo yum remove python-augeas`. I tried to reinstall with `sudo yum install python-agueas` and received back the same error. Will update my question with the error output.

Comment: Hm, Maybe you should look at the permissions of the containing directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34321/discussion-between-alfonso-and-michael-hampton).